# Play Framework: how to prevent encoded URLs from being decoded automatically

Tags: scala, razor, playframework

Given the following template (`email.scala.html`) containing an encoded url (slash replaced by `%2F`)...

```
@(sender: String, subject: String)(content: Html)

<html>
<head>
<title>@subject</title>
</head>
<body>
   ...
   <div class="footer">
     <div class="align-left">
       Trouble viewing this email?&nbsp;<a href="http://localhost:9000/viewInBrowser?email=eJy9WWl3okgX%2Fp5fUW2f7tN9jkZw...">View in browser</a>
     </div>
   </div>
   ...
</body>
</html>
```

... I always get the following URL when the template gets parsed:

```
http://localhost:9000/viewInBrowser?email=eJy9WWl3okgX/p5fUW2f7tN9jkZw...`
```

As you can see, the URL has been decoded automatically and `%2F` replaced by a slash.

Is it possible to prevent this?

Comment: Did you try doubling the percent symbols? That usually provides a shield that will survive one round of substitutions.

Comment: Tried... but it doesn't do the trick,